# Check for null in an if loop

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop, null

I am having some problems with my program. 
I am creating a script which displays all the properties in the properties table in our database and one row in the table should show available or sold. it should check if the `puserId` is null or 1 or more

```
//Execute the Query
$records = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$row['propertyId']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row['propNum']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row['AptNum']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row['street']."</td>";
 if (empty(['puserId'])) {
    $status = 'Available';
 }else {
    $status = 'Sold';
 }
 echo "<td>".$status."</td>";
```

When i use this it shows that all properties are sold, also the ones wich have a `puserId` of `null`. It doesn't give me any errors though.

Anybody knows how I should do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _Small Point_ If's dont loop man

Comment: `if (empty($row['puserId'])) {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly "`if` in a loop" I suppose

Comment: Its a Typo alert

Comment: to continue off of @Akintunde007 comment `if ($row['puserId'] !== '' || $row['puserId'] !== null) {` - but empty should be enough (unless you allow your db to store empty strings (`''`) - empty won't work on a value of `''`

Comment: Thanks @Akintunde007 that worked

Comment: also just for kicks - you can shorten that if statement: `$status = (!is_null($_POST['puserId']) ? 'Available' : 'Sold')`

Comment: [`empty(['puserId'])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) is never true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (empty(['puserId'])) {
```

with:

```
if (empty($row['puserId'])) {
```

in order to fix the missing variable `$row` typo (your actual code checks whether the array `['puserId']` is null, which is obviously false) . If your field is either null or numeric, you can also write that as:

```
if (is_null($row['puserId'])) {
```

but my advice is to avoid using empty/null values in table fields related to identifiers. Just give them a default value of 0 to make everything easier. At that point you could write your check as:

```
if ($row['puserId'] == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the `$row['puserId']` typo, `empty` doesn't really look useful there. It includes an `isset` check that is pointless considering you know that column exists. You aren't checking that any of the other columns are set before you use them. There's really no need to check that one either. Just evaluate it directly. `null` or `0` values will evaluate as `false` in the if condition..

```
if ($row['puserId']) {
    $status = 'Sold';
} else {
    $status = 'Available';
}
```